# Openpyxl, how to iterate over sheets to add an image inside each one?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to add an image to each individual sheet in the workbook however when I try to iterate over the workbook with a for loop, the program returns an error however adding to the first sheet works just fine.

Here's the code that works however it can only add to the first sheet:

```
    ws = wb.active
    img = Image('screenshot.png')
    ws.add_image(img, 'A1')
```

And this is the code that attempts to iterate over each sheet:

```
    img = Image('screenshot.png')
    for sheet in wb:
        sheet.add_image(img, 'A1')
```

And this is the error that it returns:

```
    UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'xl/media/image4.png'
```

It seems the 'wb.active' might be the problem however I'm not sure how to integrate it into the for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the fix, if anyone was wondering you have to assign the 'img' variable within the for loop:

```
    for sheet in wb:
        img = Image('screenshot.png')
        sheet.add_image(img, 'A1')
```